# How set node js morgan logger max file size

Tags: node.js, logging, nodes

I'm using node.js with morgan as logger like this:

```
// create a rotating write stream
var accessLogStream = require("stream-file-archive")({
  path: "logs/app-%Y-%m-%d.log",  // Write logs rotated by the day
  symlink: "logs/current.log",    // Maintain a symlink called current.log
  compress: true                // Gzip old log files
});

app.use(logger('combined', {stream: accessLogStream}));
```

and I wanted to know how to limit the max file size of the access.log.

Thanks

Comment: You're using `stream-file-archive` to stream the actual file, which doesn't seem to support file size limiting at all.

Comment: Ok, do you know any way to limit the size of the log file if i won't use `stream-file-archive`?

Comment: Winston's [`file transport`](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/docs/transports.md#file-transport) has a `maxsize` option.

Comment: Great thanks I will try that